bootstrap 5.3.3 input group range height (form-control collides with form-range)
the range height is wrong, I need some text to describe that its best to see the snippet...
How to fix that?


    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <form>

    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text" id=formControlRange>range</span>
      <input type="range" class="form-range form-control" aria-describedby="formControlRange">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text" id=formControlText>text</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="formControlText">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 




.form-range applies height: 1.5rem, so overwrite that with height: auto

smort - thanks - i was looking exactly for this answer
